# How is it possible to call a different controller's method in ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Inside another controller I get the application controller as following (as it is defined via needs):

```
appCtrl = this.get('controllers.application');
```

Accessing or setting properties works fine, e.g.

```
appCtrl.set("property", true);
```

will trigger registered listeners.

But I am not able to call a method of the application controller, e.g. assume there exists function x in the application controller. Then the following call fails as appCtrl contains no function x:

```
appCtrl.x();
```

I also tried defining x as an action in the application controller and triggering from outside as following:

```
appCtrl.send("x");
```

This also did not work.

How am I supposed to call a function of the application controller from another controller?

Comment: not sure why it doesn't work, but what are you trying to accomplish? might be a better way with actions.

Comment: I also tried it with actions. The error is functionally identical. It says there was no response to the action in my console.

Comment: I mean there are definitely workarounds. The data can be passed differently, but it makes the code unnecessarily bloated, and I just wondered why this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried something simple and didn't seem to have a problem. Here's a JSbin:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/borejamufo/3/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Hmm, interesting. It's kind of mindboggling. Although my setup is a bit more complicated with ember-cli there is no fundamental difference... Thanks, at least I know it should work in principle now.

Comment: Ok, I found it out. I stupidly had a typo in my application controller file name and as I was only using it for properties before I did not actually notice it was never loaded... :(

Thanks for bringing me back on track.